# ¿Qué hace y para qué se utilizan los métodos con la palabra reservada "this" antes del parámetro de una función?

Tags: c#, this

¡Hola a todos!

Estaba revisando el código de alguien más y me encontré con ciertos métodos que me generaron cierta inquietud.

Miré que antes del parámetro de los métodos colocan la palabra reservada "this". Ejemplo de código a continuación:

```
public static Entidad2 FromDtoToModel(this Entidad entity)
        {
            return new Entidad2
            {
                Name = entity.Name,
                       .
                       .
                Fecha = entity.Fecha
            };
        }
```

y bueno, para hacer el "llamado" de dichas funciones solo crean la instancia de cierta clase, algo así como lo muestra el siguiente código:

```
Entidad entidad = new Entidad();
entidad.FromDtoToModel();
```

Me gustaría estudiar más a fondo sobre el tema y para esto he 'gloogleado' para encontrar el tópico pero no he podido encontrar algo que me ayude. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme dándome más información sobre la estructura dicha función, en qué casos serían útiles? y si no, pues con decirme el tema / tópico de lo que trata bastaría para estudiar dicho tema.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por si a alguien más le interesa el tema les que comentaré que, gracias a la respuesta de @Antonio S.F. he logrado dar con el tema: "Métodos de extensión" y de paso dejaré dos enlaces que me ayudaron:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

https://www.genbeta.com/desarrollo/metodos-de-extension-en-c

Comment: Ricardo, si la respuesta te satisface (debería, es la correcta: Métodos de extensión), considera aceptarla

Comment: @Arriel Ya la he aceptado como respuesta. Gracias por estar pendiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien, lo que has visto es la forma de extender una clase. Hay veces que precisamos que una clase ya creada se comporte o haga algo que está ligado a la propia clase. La forma más normal de hacer una extensión de una clase sería crear nuestra propia clase de extensiones. Un ejemplo para extender la clase Color:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class OwnExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Obtiene la tonalidad en escala de grises para un color dado.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="p_ColorToGrayScale">Color a transformar en grayscale</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Color ToGrayScale(this Color p_ColorToGrayScale)
        {
            int l_Gray = (int)(p_ColorToGrayScale.R * 0.3f + p_ColorToGrayScale.G * 0.59f + p_ColorToGrayScale.B * 0.11f);

            return Color.FromArgb(p_ColorToGrayScale.A, l_Gray, l_Gray, l_Gray);
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando llamamos al método no le pasamos un parámetro ya que al estar este definido como ***this*** el parámetro el método pasa a ser del propio objeto Color. Una llamada sería de la siguiente forma:

```
Color miColor = Color.Red;
Color enEscalaDeGrises = miColor.ToGrayScale();
```

Algo común suele ser también extender el objeto string ya que solemos manejarnos mucho con cadenas dentro de una aplicación; así que otro ejemplo, en este caso para extender el objeto string donde crearemos un método que devuelta n caracteres del final de la cadena y que se puede incluir dentro de nuestra clase OwnExtensions:

```
/// <summary>
/// Obtiene un subcadena desde la posición final
/// </summary>
/// <param name="p_Text">Cadena de texto de donde se va a extraer la subcadena.</param>
/// <param name="p_Length">Longitud de la subcadena a extraer por la parte derecha.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetRightPart(this string p_Text, int p_Length)
{
    if (p_Text.Length < p_Length)
        return p_Text;
    else
        return p_Text.Substring(p_Text.Length - p_Length, p_Length);
}
```

Observa que nuevamente con this este método pasa a ser una extensión del objeto string, pero tiene un segundo parámetro que en nuestro caso sería el parámetro que le pasamos a la extensión, la llamada sería de la siguiente forma:

```
string matricula = "5431-DNJ";
// Obtenemos 3 caracteres de la derecha de la cadena.
string parteDerecha = matricula.GetRightPart(3);
```